# Error when I want to enter Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: boot, permissions, 22.04, init, disk-formatting

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my Dell Inspiron 13 7000 2-in-1 two months ago and last Friday I tried to enter Ubuntu but got an unexpected error Last time I used it there was no problem.

[image]

I tried with the other screens with the keys Crtl + Alt + F2/F3/F4/F5/F6 then log in with my username and then tried to fix it with the startx command but got the error message in the picture below.

Any suggestions other than  disk-formatting?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you try running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade`? Sometimes, performing an upgrade fixes such issues.

Comment: Try disabling TPM in BIOS/UEFI

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I tried with sudo apt update and sudo apt full-upgrade after going to the second screen with crtl + alt + F2 but still can't enter ubuntu. In the first screen I can't type anything. Now, how do I go to the BIOS/UEFI?